# Finding distance in an octahedron

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question that likely is very simple to the community here. I would like to ask about calculating two distances in an octahedron, could someone please help to let me know if my logic is correct? Thank you so much!

[Octahedron point distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQxoe.png)

Distance AB:
For an edge length of a, the diagonal of base rectangle is ~1.41a, so distance AB is 1/3 x 1.41a = 0.47a

Distance AC:
The height of octahedron is ~1.42a and therefore distance BC is 2/3 x 1.42a = 0.94a. Following this, distance AC can be calculated as a square root of (AB x AB + BC x BC) = ~1.05a

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE!. Hint for AB: Let the top of the octahedron be O, the square be EFGH (with E being the point straight from B and G being the point straight from A). Now use the similar triangle property on triangles OAB and OEG.

Comment: For BC: Let the bottom of the octahedron be O', and use the similar triangle property on OEO' and BEC to get the length of BC. This will allow you to calculate for AC